# Android testing - Robolectric + Mockito + Retrofit getting Wanted but not invoked error

Tags: java, android, mockito, retrofit, robolectric

Trying to use Robolectric and Mockito to test my Retrofit calls in my Android app but I am getting the following error:

> Wanted but not invoked: mockApi.register(
>       ,
>        );
>   -> at ServiceTest.testAPI(ServiceTest.java:58) Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

The RetroFit API call is defined in an interface as follows:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/register")
void register(
        @FieldMap Map<String, String> registrationParams,
        Callback<JsonObject> response) ;
```

My test class is as follows:

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
@RunWith(TestRunner.class)
public class SharedServiceTest {

private RegistrationActivity activity;
@Mock
private SharedService mockApi;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Callback<JsonObject>> cb;


@Before
public void setUp() {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    ActivityController<RegistrationActivity> controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(RegistrationActivity.class);
    activity = controller.get();

    controller.create();
}

@Test
public void testAPI() throws Exception {

    activity.populateFields();
    activity.validateFields();
    activity.register("");

    Mockito.verify(mockApi).register(Mockito.anyMap(), cb.capture());

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("sessionToken", Mockito.anyString());
    jsonObject.addProperty("userId", Mockito.anyString());

    cb.getValue().success(jsonObject, null);

    Assert.assertTrue(ShadowToast.getTextOfLatestToast().contains("Registration completed"));

}

}
```

The method in my RegistrationActivity that uses the API is as follows:

```
public void register(){

       MyApplication.getInstance().getSharedService().register(mRegistrationParams, new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void success(JsonObject jsonObject, retrofit.client.Response response) {
                Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Registration completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, RetrofitUtils.getErrorMessage(error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

The real Retrofit service comes from my own Application class which I have mocked in my test folder for robolectric to use:

```
public class TestMyApplication extends MyApplication
        implements TestLifecycleApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override public void beforeTest(Method method) {
    }

    @Override public void prepareTest(Object test) {
    }

    @Override public void afterTest(Method method) {
    }

    @Override public CPSharedService getCPSharedService() {
        return Mockito.mock(SharedService.class);
    }
}
```

I have searched over the other questions on SO that have this error but none of them match what I am trying to do here or provide a solution to my issue so I am just wondering what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mocked instance of `SharedService` in your `TestMyApplication` is not the same you declared your test class.
The `Mockito.verify(mockApi).register(Mockito.anyMap(), cb.capture());`   is failing because the instance referred by `mockApi` field is actually never called.
Another problem is that the getter in `TestMyApplication` always returns a new mock for each invokation:

```
    @Override public CPSharedService getCPSharedService() {
        return Mockito.mock(SharedService.class); //this creates a new "mocked" instance 
    }
```

Your scenario is not 100% clear to me, but it would be better if you could let your test set the instance of the mockApi field in your TestMyApplication instance:

```
public class TestMyApplication extends MyApplication
        implements TestLifecycleApplication {

    private SharedService sharedService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override public void beforeTest(Method method) {
    }

    @Override public void prepareTest(Object test) {
    }

    @Override public void afterTest(Method method) {
    }

    @Override public CPSharedService getCPSharedService() {
        return this.sharedService;
    }

    public void setCPSharedService(SharedService sharedService) {
        // store your mock
        this.sharedService = sharedService;
    }
}
```

and in your test class:

```
@Test
public void testAPI() throws Exception  {

    // configure you TestMyApplication
    assertTrue(MyApplication.getInstance() instanceof TestMyApplication);
    TestMyApplication testMyApp = (TestMyApplication) MyApplication.getInstance();
    testMyApp.setCPSharedService(this.mockApi);

    activity.populateFields();
    activity.validateFields();
    activity.register("");

    Mockito.verify(this.mockApi).register(Mockito.anyMap(), cb.capture());

    ...

}
```